# Does fumaric acid form maleic anhydride upon heating?

Tags: organic-chemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

Maleic acid (the *cis* isomer of the dicarboxylic acid $\ce{C4H4O4}$) readily forms its anhydride on heating. Clayden's organic chemistry textbook mentions this as a point of distinction between it and fumaric acid (the *trans* isomer), which fails to dehydrate to its anhydride upon heating. However, I have discovered that at temperatures above 200 $^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$, fumaric acid forms maleic anhydride as well.

Which is the correct answer? I don't think it is likely that fumaric acid can form the anhydride - even at higher temperatures - given the *trans* configuration and restricted rotation.

Comment: Some  calculations (values from NIST) reveal that the formation of maleic anhydride and water from fumaric acid is an endothermic reaction ($\Delta H\approx +65.28 \frac{kJ}{mol}$) but the change in entropy is positive ($\Delta S\approx 134.24 \frac{J}{mol\cdot K}$). This means that the reaction becomes spontaneous for temperatures above $213^\circ C$, but this is only "mildly" spontaneous ($\Delta G\approx -5 \frac{kJ}{mol}$ at $523\ K$). So, the use of a dehydrating agent to remove the water from the reaction mixture and drive the equilibrium forward (Le Chatelier's principle) is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Fumaric acid does form maleic anhydride due to partial combustion. From [wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fumaric_acid) of fumaric acid:

> Fumaric acid converts to the irritant maleic anhydride, upon partial
>   combustion.

Also, dehydrating fumaric acid with a  dehydrating agent also forms maleic anhydride. [This paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01133a521) describe how to convert $\ce{C^{14}}$ labelled fumaric acid to maleic anhydride.

> Maleic anhydride-2-$\ce{C^{14}}$ is readily obtained from fumaric
>   acid-2-$\ce{C^{14}}$ through dehydration using phosphorus pentoxide
>   getting 96% yield under controlled condition.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your reasoning but it *really seems* that fumaric acid forms the anhydride.

According to [*the Wikipedia page on maleic acid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maleic_acid#Isomerization_to_fumaric_acid)
the isomerization process (from maleic to fumaric) is rather easy.